# How to display non-english characters in wx

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Is there a way to display non-english characters in buttons and message dialogues?

For example, I need characters like ż, ć, ą, etc. When the button's label is supposed to say "Usuń sekwencje" it says that instead:
[image]

I use wxPython in version 4.0.4, code of this example button:

```
usunsek=wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Usuń sekwencje', pos=(420,45))
```

Comment: Please provide more information: the sample code used to display this button, and the version of wxwidgets you use

Comment: @Simek, what platform? Does OS you are testing on support the locale you are trying? Is wxPython demo works for you?

Comment: @Simek Please create a minimalistic Google Colab demo of the issue.

Comment: I use unicode strings for these cases, e.g.: usunsek=wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, u'Usuń sekwencje', pos=(420,45))